# How to extend the criteria of OrderDocumentCriteria in Shopware 6, DocumentOrderCriteriaEvent no longer exists

Tags: shopware6

I would like to extend the Criteria on creating a document.
I am missing the products as an association to extend the document templates. 
Unfortunately, DocumentOrderCriteriaEvent no longer exists.
How can I extend the Criteria when a document is created?
SW now use a static methode to create the Criteria, thats all, no event to manipulate the Criteria anymore.

```
$criteria = \Shopware\Core\Checkout\Document\Renderer\OrderDocumentCriteriaFactory::create()
```

Thanks for helping